# Clone Github project anonymously

Tags: github, tor

In my office github included in blocked list by network administrator. Is possible for me to running some protocol of git client (like to clone project) anonymousle via Tor/Vidalia?

Comment: Use HTTP proxy site for browsing and download a zipball or tarball f the repository.

Comment: If I need to push anonymously?

Comment: Not sure if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy sites. there are many..

**`http://hidemyass.com`** is one among them. Once you have opened it, type github.com in the address bar of hidemyass.com site.

Browse the repo you want to clone.

I used this proxy site to access FB, Orkut and other blocked sites when i was studying college.

**Note:** There are limited access you will get. Try it!!

Thanks

Comment: if I need to push my project to github, how?